# Cannot import library, shown in Java RESTful Web Services tutorial, into my NetBeans project

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, jersey

I am working on a RESTful Web Services tutorial **[here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices_Part2/RESTfulWebservicesPart2.htm)**.

I got to step #4a which reads:

> Import the following packages.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import playerentities.Player;
```

However, I also noticed they have an import that I don't:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;
```

So I attempted to add the import to my project.

My problem is that the jersey libraries are, apparentlly, not making themselves available to my NetBeans project. I downloaded the jersey libraries from **[here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html)**, unzipped the archive, and added the JAR files to the project library. There also appear to be libraries in the project that were provided by NetBeans.

When I look at the Libraries folder in the Project view, all of the libraries appear to be there. Still, I keep getting the error:

```
package com.sun.jersey.api.client does not exist.
```

I am using NetBeans 8.2, which is the latest version, so I should be good.

So, what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the code require this imports? If no, I'd suggest not paying attention to the imports you don't need. Looks like the tutorial is based on NetBeans 7 and relies on some pregenerated code / template.

This code may differ from version to version of NetBeans. You are using 8.x version, whereas tutorial was written for 7-th

Comment: Frankly, I got to the point where i threw everything at it. I know is uses jersey (it says so in the import), so that's why I downloaded and [tried to] import the libraries.

Comment: Part 1 of the tutorial says that you need only Java + Netbeans to complete it. NetBeans provides itself:

Creating RESTful Web Services
Supports testing of RESTful Web Services
Building client applications that access RESTful Web Services. So it should provide necessary libraries

Comment: I did see that, but sometimes tutorials leave out steps. I thought they were thinking "Everybody knows you need jersey for REST." Well, rats ... I guess I'll have to hunt for a new, not broken, tutorial.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest completin all the steps carefully. From quick view of part 1 you are creating a project from web template and it adds several libraries to the classpath. This is exactly why the templates exist